# Element UI multiple select auto width

Tags: css, vuejs2, element-ui

I would like to use [multiple choice selector](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select#basic-multiple-select), but would like to have a flexible width, i.e. having its width growing according to selected items.

Here is the code without the flexible behavior, I tried many things but could not achieve what I want:

```js
var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        options: [{
          value: 'Option1',
          label: 'Option1'
        }, {
          value: 'Option2',
          label: 'Option2'
        }, {
          value: 'Option3',
          label: 'Option3'
        }, {
          value: 'Option4',
          label: 'Option4'
        }, {
          value: 'Option5',
          label: 'Option5'
        }, {
          value: 'Option6',
          label: 'Option6'
        }],
        value: ''
      }
    }
  }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/2.15.6/index.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/2.15.6/theme-chalk/index.min.css" integrity="sha512-oKuj7gKXGxOZuCSvOPZE1seWosmP4iy608AyAH4hPnGD6tPX4325S+wo6MJQz+L3Hq4tK3e0RMfu+TDFUZFrgA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div id="app">
  <template>
    <el-select v-model="value" multiple placeholder="Select">
    <el-option
      v-for="item in options"
      :key="item.value"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item.value">
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
  </template>
</div>
```